# Errors: XPC connection interrupted | Terminating since there is no system app

Tags: ios, swift

I recently updated to Xcode 8.1 and coding in Swift 3.

I am developing an iOS app and I get the following errors when the iPad Simulator is placed in the Landscape orientation.  I do not get the errors when I use the iPhone Simulator in the Landscape orietation.

XPC connection interrupted | Terminating since there is no system app.

On Xcode 8.0, I did not get these errors.  I have restarted my Mac Mini and Reset the Simulator to see if that would clear the errors.  Neither worked.

Comment: Have you opened a bug report with Apple? If so, post the number here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62666065/7106170

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this behaviour in 2 cases when migrating the code to swift 3:

1. Forgot to add `@escaping`:

   ```
   sendReceipt(completion: @escaping (Receipt) -> () ){
       // var to retain the closure
       self.completion = completion
   }
   ```
2. Adding a value to a Lazy var.

   ```
   lazy var foo : Example = { return Example() }()

   // later in another method
   foo = Example()
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I found that when I upgraded to Xcode 8.1, I could only target iOS 9.2 (error went away) and not iOS 9.0 as I had done previously.

I did not put an Apple bug report in the system.